# Construct URLs from Routes asp.net web form 4.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-routing

i am using asp.net 4.0 webform project and routing. i need to know the actual page that's handling the request. suppose my routing url is like

http://mysite.com/product/audi
basically i have product.aspx page and audi is passed as query string value. actually product.aspx is handling the request. can i programatically extract the page name and query string name and data. as a result i can build url later like

http://mysite.com/product.aspx?cat=audi

please help me to build url with query string from routed url.
thanks

**Added portion**

when we map route in global.asax like

```
`protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
 RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); 
}
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{ 
 routes.MapPageRoute("","Product/{category}","~/Product.aspx");
}
```

then we get route path like http://www.mysite.com/products/software but internal url look like http://www.mysite.com/products.aspx?category=software. so i just need to reverse.i will pass the url like http://www.mysite.com/products/software to any routine and routine will return url to me like      http://www.mysite.com/products.aspx?category=software. just tell me how could i do this.

Comment: can i construct url looping in Page.RouteData.Values.  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in Page.RouteData.Values)   
 {   
 lblAllValues.Text += "Key: " + kvp.Key + " Value: " + kvp.Value + "<br />";   
 }  http://vbcity.com/blogs/dowhilesomething/archive/2010/05/15/seo-friendly-sites-using-system-web-routing-with-asp-net-4-0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From ScottGu's Blog:

**Retrieving URLs within an ASP.NET Web Form**

The URL routing engine in ASP.NET can be used to both map incoming URLs to code handlers, as well as be used to pro grammatically generate outgoing URLs using the same mapping registration logic.

For example, above when we mapped the /products/{category} URL we gave it a “friendly name” of “products-browse”.  This allows us to now also use the new Page.GetRouteUrl() helper method to lookup the route within the URL routing system, optionally specify parameters to it, and then retrieve an actual URL that it maps back to.  For example, the below code would retrieve a URL value of “/products/software”:

[image]

[URL Routing with ASP.NET 4 Web Forms (VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 Series)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

Comment: i hope u did not understand my question. i update my question please have look & provide solution if u have any. thanks